# Property 'count' not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray *' PO command in lldb

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm using the console to `po` some variables, in this case I have a `NSMutableArray`, I want to see its count. I get a wonderful error.

Any ideas?

I am aware I can see the count in the variable list (it says @"1 object"), but I seem to have this error for multiple getters and properties while using `po`.

UPDATE: Seems like the square bracket notation is the key, and casting to int makes it readable.

Comment: Have you tried casting the variable? (`po (NSMutableArray *)myarray`).  I think this is a bug/missing feature in the debugger.

Comment: Yeah, same error. However if you do something like this:

Comment: po [(NSMutableArray *) array count]
   (id) $4 = 0x00000003

Comment: In fact no need to cast, but to get a "human" friendly display you need to cast to int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use    `(gdb) p (int)[array count]`