# lldb error: property not found on object of type

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, lldb

I am trying to debug my iOS app using lldb and I'm getting really weird errors on debug.

A few lines before my breakpoint, I've got:

`CGRect frame = view.frame;`

Which I can access with no problems with `print frame` command in lldb. However, when I try to access the frame again in lldb, I type `print view.frame` and get the following error:

`error: property 'frame' not found on object of type 'UIView *'`

This doesn't make sense as I can verify the `view` is a `UIView*` instance and has a valid property called frame by typing `po view` and getting correct results:

`(UIView *) $4 = 0x1e199bf0 <MyAppCustomView: 0x1e199bf0; frame = (3398 3396; 204 208); layer = <CALayer: 0x1e199ce0>>`

This particular lldb error happens to me *a lot*, and I couldn't find the cause of this error. Someone suggested at [Property 'count' not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray *' PO command in lldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567455/property-count-not-found-on-object-of-type-nsmutablearray-po-command-in-ll) that one could use gdb as `(gdb) p view.frame` but I'm getting `error: '(gdb)' is not a valid command.` and I highly suspect that a gdb command would "work?" inside another debugger anyway.

Any suggestions or workarounds for this bug which occurs randomly?

Comment: already tried: error: no known method '-frame'; cast the message send to the method's return type

Comment: print [(UIView*)view frame] doesnt work either

Comment: print (CGRect)[view frame]

Comment: That happens also to me sometimes.In this case I just use NSLog() or assign it to a temporarily object/struct that I will print with lldb.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri it is one workaround, but it's not very convenient while you are debugging and need the value of some variable and you haven't nslogged it.

Comment: It looks like you need to use GDB instead of LLDB, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515630/lldb-fails-to-print-variable-values-with-error-reference-to-id-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Dot notation for message sending is not supported in lldb when using Objective-C.  Use bracket notation and cast the result to CGRect:

```
p (CGRect)[view frame]
```

Comment: (lldb) p [view frame]
error: no known method '-frame'; cast the message send to the method's return type

Comment: after the edit it worked. any reasons why I should explicityly cast it? and any ideas why it would be occuring sometimes, and otherwise, lldb is just working flawless with po/print without any casts?

Comment: @canpoyrazoğlu Because when LLDB queries the runtime, it is not aware of the types of the non-objects you want to print, casting gives it a promised type.

Comment: @CodaFi OK, now I'm curious. Why does LLDB really care about types? Why doesn't it just run the code and see if it works?

Comment: @ssdscott 's answer should be the accepted answer,it does not work without the outer prarentheses

Answer (score 3):

Just in case the above doesn't work (which it didn't for me, looking for the frame for a variable cell, class derived from UITableViewCell): forcing the extra parentheses seemed to help lldb's little ditty brain:

```
p ((CGRect)[cell frame])
```

presto magico:

```
(CGRect) $5 = origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=320, height=44)
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer since that lldb still complain without the outer parentheses.

Comment: The "above" phrase in your answer can change context, point to a specific answer please.

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable (uncheck) Thread Sanitizer in Xcode > Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Diagnostics. With Thread Sanitizer enabled I wasn't able to access many NSView properties (e.g. bounds, frame) through LLDB.